# What is the easiest way to migrate a WordPress website from an old host to a new one

Tags: wordpress

What is the easiest way to migrate a **WordPress** website from an old host to a new one ?

I tried to use the WordPress plugin [Duplicator](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/), but it didn't seem to work because I got this error:

> Interruption de l’assemblage par l’hébergement (FR)
>   This server cannot complete the build due to setup constraints. (EN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, normally different host have different pathways from server and some other minor details that can give you problems when using plugins for migration, so is best to make a separated backup from your files and a backup of your database and them up load all of them on the new host.

still, if you want to try other plugins for that,  follow this list:
http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/7-best-wordpress-backup-plugins-compared-pros-and-cons/

Comment: thank you for your reply, this is what i did and it's work